# an unexpected request with sec-fetch-mode: none, who triggered it?

Tags: google-chrome, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-mode

I send a request ONLY ONCE in the browser but got 2 requests logged in the server. One of them is not expected and I wonder which mechanism triggered it.

### The details

1. Only under Chrome (see the HTTP header for version). Safari does not trigger it.
2. Both of the logged requests are GET requests ( not a preflight I guess )

The differences are in the headers as below shows

[image]

The left one is what I'm expecting, as you can see my custom header 'abc'='123' there. The right one I don't really get where is it come from.

I checked ['Sec-fetch-site': 'none'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site) saying that it's a user operation triggered request. But what I do is simply refreshing the browser. And as you can see from 'Referer' header on the left, what I refresh is `"localhost:3111/lp/..."` not `"/sources.list"`

### The complete headers (don't read, just FYI)

First (expected)

```
[
  [ 'Host', 'localhost:3111' ],
  [ 'Connection', 'keep-alive' ],
  [
    'sec-ch-ua',
    '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"'
  ],
  [ 'abc', '123' ],
  [ 'content-type', 'application/json' ],
  [ 'sec-ch-ua-mobile', '?0' ],
  [
    'User-Agent',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
  ],
  [ 'sec-ch-ua-platform', '"macOS"' ],
  [ 'Accept', '*/*' ],
  [ 'Sec-Fetch-Site', 'same-origin' ],
  [ 'Sec-Fetch-Mode', 'cors' ],
  [ 'Sec-Fetch-Dest', 'empty' ],
  [
    'Referer',
    'http://localhost:3111/lp/44104bf9-c011-4b76-9b28-81416711e827'
  ],
  [ 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br' ],
  [ 'Accept-Language', 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7' ],
  [
    'Cookie',
    'sessions=%7B%7D; lastSignedIn=emailMagicLink; Idea-2c8ec7e9=7040e8cb-a902-4428-aa83-ee204ad56626; _xsrf=2|25b6023f|81dc3651ce8f50fb7837c48818d2a02a|1677900074; express_sid=s%3AqccgB6sOcy5YBP_MxUDbknYuUGkm8fH3.OFKlxJBixG8AVlmVhdwcoaxnb1W0ibR4N%2BHBRWreFEM; token=t.RmzJJ4wvn8AGgzk6kszg; prefsHttp={%22chatAlwaysVisible%22:true}'
  ]
]
```

The second (NOT expected)

```
 [
  [ 'Host', 'localhost:3111' ],
  [ 'Connection', 'keep-alive' ],
  [
    'sec-ch-ua',
    '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"'
  ],
  [ 'sec-ch-ua-mobile', '?0' ],
  [
    'User-Agent',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
  ],
  [ 'sec-ch-ua-platform', '"macOS"' ],
  [ 'Accept', '*/*' ],
  [ 'Sec-Fetch-Site', 'none' ],
  [ 'Sec-Fetch-Mode', 'cors' ],
  [ 'Sec-Fetch-Dest', 'empty' ],
  [ 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br' ],
  [ 'Accept-Language', 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7' ],
  [
    'Cookie',
    'sessions=%7B%7D; lastSignedIn=emailMagicLink; Idea-2c8ec7e9=7040e8cb-a902-4428-aa83-ee204ad56626; _xsrf=2|25b6023f|81dc3651ce8f50fb7837c48818d2a02a|1677900074; express_sid=s%3AqccgB6sOcy5YBP_MxUDbknYuUGkm8fH3.OFKlxJBixG8AVlmVhdwcoaxnb1W0ibR4N%2BHBRWreFEM; token=t.RmzJJ4wvn8AGgzk6kszg; prefsHttp={%22chatAlwaysVisible%22:true}'
  ]
]
```

Comment: Can you share the client-side code that triggers the expected request?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I'm using trpc so the triggering code is a bit complex (it's not plain old fetch/xhr). But what I can tell you is that when I filter the url requested in the chrome network tab there's only 1 request sent

Comment: I just setup a proxy server, which eliminates the chances of my server logging bug,  and it indicates that there are indeed 2 requests received. So I guess it's chrome since there's only 1 requests in the network tab